# Nissan micra 1.1 engine management light on, common fault?

Tags: electrical, nissan, wiring

Is this a common fault on the micra? Will the light go out if battery is disconnected, as some people claim? Obviously it would come back if there is an actual fault.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you provide some more information? Year of the vehicle would be very helpful. Also, did anything happen or was something changed around the time the light came on?

Comment: Yes, I will find out more, it's my daughters car, she only just got it and the light was on from the start and as she lives away it's hard for me to assess.

Comment: No worries. If you can get a picture of the exact light that may help too. Some cars have a lot of indicator lights.

Comment: Avoid disconnecting the battery to clear the malfunction indicator light. You can lose adaptives, cause other problems and it probably won't solve the initial problem.

Comment: If she's only just got the car, and it's from a dealer, I'd suggest taking it back and getting them to fix it under warranty...